# Accessing the URL and writing values into the fields

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I have access for only to a front end of a webpage.

This webpage has fields like

```
Name
Age
Number
```

For the above i have to update **Number** field.

Similarly there are hundreds of similar webpages with the these fields which are needed to be updated.

For example URL of this webpage is https://stackoverflow.com/id=xx

In the URL the value xx of the 'id' is unique for each webpage.

I have these values xx of the 'id' and the corresponding age which needs to be updated in the webpages iteratively and be saved.

What are ways for doing the above?

Comment: *"...needs to be updated in the webpages iteratively and be saved."* What do you mean by "saved"?

Comment: Updated where? Can you give an example of what you want to do exactly?

Comment: For example this webpage has save button, so after the Number field has been updated in the field it needs to saved. I said saved because as it is a iterative process.

Comment: I think what you try to mean of save is update the values on the database where you store the url do I get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have them displayed in a single page or paginate it instead of having to view them one per page, one item per line, put the values that would be changeable in a `input type=text` with a corresponding submit button beside each.

Answer (score 0):

well you could get url parameters by using $_POST['id'], $_GET['id'] or $_REQUEST['id'] but try to validate the values first to avoid sql injections.

if you want to get the whole url itself you could use

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

$_SERVER is default variable on php it has a lot of uses just try to visit this link http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.

I hope it helps. :)